# Why stochastic gradient descent does not support non-linear SVM

Tags: machine-learning, svm

I have read that SGD supports linear SVM, but not non-linear SVM. Why is that? I was looking at the cost function of non-linear SVM. It does has a "sum" sign in the beginning.

Comment: You need a source instead of saying "I read it"

Comment: I read it from wikipedia. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stochastic_gradient_descent . I also found ML libraries such as Apache Spark does not provide SVM with SGD training function.

Comment: Could you show what you read and where? Please be specific.

Comment: Here is a relevant citation from "Deep Learning" by Goodfellow et al.: "Prior to the advent of deep learning, the main way to learn nonlinear models was to use the kernel trick in combination with a linear model. Many kernel learning algorithms require constructing an m × m matrix G(i,j) = k(x (i), x (j)). Constructing this matrix has computational cost O(m^2), which is clearly undesirable for datasets with billions of examples." Here **m** is the number of examples and **x(i)** is the **i**-th example.

Answer (score 0):

Please read about Mercer Theorem. Maybe, it will shed some light!

Comment: It has nothing to do with the solver. Mercer Theorem states what is a valid Kernel for SVM. not if GD can be used or not.